# Suggestions for the Second Brainstorming Session

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat-sessions

we'll be having our second Brainstorming session in **[chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/anime-and-manga)** this Saturday at 20:00 UTC.

The **[last session](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348/january-30th-brainstorming-session-results#comment701_348)** discussed about list questions and recruiting members.

This new session will be more open, since the "major" issues were discussed. So I'd like the community members to speak up, and raise *major, site-wide issues*.

We will also look into the progress made with the decisions from the previous session in the brief time elapsed.

What I want to ask from you guys, is **raise the issues you think that should be discussed**. If you raise an issue, you're expected to be on the session to share your opinion!

Hope to see you there!

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to raise the following issues:

- **Phrasing of our [FAQ page](https://anime.stackexchange.com/faq).**
- Phrasing of our [/about page](https://anime.stackexchange.com/about).

More specific issues:

- The **[cartoon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/69/what-differentiates-anime-from-regular-cartoons)** question.

Comment: In the about page, we should definitely edit the "Ask about..." and "Don't ask about..." part.

Comment: @JNat: Save it for the session :)

Comment: And I think the [Type A vs. Type B question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/what-are-type-a-and-type-b-viewers) also falls under the same category as the [Cartoon vs. Anime question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/69/what-differentiates-anime-from-regular-cartoons). The only difference is that the Type A vs. Type B question has a more clear-cut answer with much less room for debate.

Comment: @Mysticial: Not exactly. Type A and Type B are a lot more confined and well defined than what "Anime" and "Cartoons" are. The differences are clear and explicit.

Comment: Hence the "much less room for debate". Since it's generally agreed upon what a Type A vs. Type B is.