# How far can we go with questions related to anime?

Tags: support, allowed-topics

If been pondering about this one for a while and seen some of them pop up. How far are we allowed to go with questions that don't directly affect an anime but a more Regular like question about anime such as:

*Will you ever "grow out" of anime? —*
[other example on site](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2646/how-did-the-angry-symbol-originate)

I know questions like;

*What is your favourite anime soundtrack? —* [other Example on site](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/im-looking-for-a-list-of-humorous-anime-similar-to-oruchuban-ebichu)

are not appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions about anime *in general* are allowed, and encouraged. We don't need in-universe questions *only*.

Look at the FAQ for example:

> Anime and Manga - Stack Exchange is a Q&A site for enthusiastic anime
>   and manga fans. This includes questions about:
>
> - Plot, character, or setting explanations
> - Historical or societal context of an anime or manga
> - Anime and manga identification
> - Franchise/series reading or viewing order
> - Anime and manga production
> - Tropes, terminology and other general anime and manga related information.

Not all of these are directly on specific anime.

The second example you gave is a list question, we've had a chat discussion over it and defined rules about questions whose answer is a list. You can read it here: **[What is the status of list questions on this site?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348/what-is-the-status-of-list-questions-on-this-site)**

Comment: That answers it thanks allot ^^