# A close reason for recommendations and lists?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

Can we get a close reason for recommendations and/or list questions? These seem to be coming up more frequently so a custom close reason would be great. Something like (I wrote this in 30 seconds so it could use tweaking):

> This question is off-topic because [list questions are considered not a good fit for our site]. However, once you have [20 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) you can stop by [our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/) and ask some of our community members.

The braced part could link to a meta thread such as [this one](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/470/274) but I leave that up to discussion/moderator consensus.

Comment: Are "too broad" and "primarily opinion based" not good enough? IMO either of those is fine for most of these questions, and a link to the help center can be given in the comments fairly quickly.

Comment: @LoganM In some cases I don't think they're specific enough. They seem misleading (IMO) in the sense that a "too broad" list question might beg for a more narrowly defined list question; "primarily opinion-based" on recommendations is likely fine, though a custom close reason is just more informative.

Answer (score 1):

Another imperfect take:

> Questions seeking for anime or manga recommendations are off-topic because they are often relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked.

Or using SO:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a manga, anime or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Anime & Manga as they tend to attract opinionated answers.

Of course, the questions asking for *lists* can be closed as too broad and the ones asking for recommendations as Primarily opinion based.