# How should we deal with out-of-universe list questions in general?

Tags: discussion, list-questions

The problem we are having with questions such as [this one](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3758/list-of-anime-with-correct-animation-of-the-characters-playing-musical-instrumen) is that the scope can be too broad at times and be ambiguous or hard to completely answer.

How should we deal with these types of questions?

Comment: what does out of universe mean?

Comment: Not matters not pertaining to the world indicated by the series (anime/manga world vs real life world)

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ [this one](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3758/list-of-anime-with-correct-animation-of-the-characters-playing-musical-instrumen) 404 Page Not Found

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jon Lin puts it quite well [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348/what-is-the-status-of-list-questions-on-this-site/574#574). To come up with a complete answer, at least in principle you would need to know about every anime ever. That isn't feasible, so every answer on such questions would necessarily be incomplete.

After some debate in out [7th Chat Cast](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/list-questions-revisited-how-to-deal-with-in-and-out-of-univese-questions-7), we decide that questions that ask for an out-of-universe list are discouraged (but you are welcome to ask them in [our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/anime-and-manga)) and will usually be to be closed as "Not Constructive," however exceptions will be made depending on how well-defined the scope of the question is.

LoganM makes a good point [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=9603152#9603152):

> In situations like the one Jon Lin mentioned ("How many Lupin III movies/specials didn't have Fujiko?") it is reasonable to keep the question open, because it's only drawing from a small set of anime in the first place.

Comment: I got 404 when accessing the link http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/list-questions-revisited-how-to-deal-with-in-and-out-of-univese-questions. Weird.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thank you. The broken link has been rectified.